# Error does not exist NUM_PAGES kotlin FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have been converting this code from java to kotlin:

```
private class ScreenSliderPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        public ScreenSliderPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:
                    SwipeFragement1 tab1 = new SwipeFragement1();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    SwipeFragement2 tab2 = new SwipeFragement2();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    SwipeFragemen3 tab3 = new SwipeFragement3();
                    return tab3;
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
```

I went looking and looking for solutions, however I came across this one that tells me that NUM_PAGES cannot be found:

```
private class ScreenSliderPagerAdapter (fm : FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm, FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)
    {
        val fm : FragmentManager = fm

        @Override
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment
        {
            when(position)
            {
                0 -> return SwipeFragement1()
                1 -> return SwipeFragement2()
                2 -> return SwipeFragement3()
            }
        }
        @Override
        override fun getCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES
    }
```

here is the error capture:
[image]

Please if someone knows about this help me, that I am new to kotlin, and if there are better ways to do it much better for me thanks

Comment: replace NUM_PAGES with 3. Basically its the number of pages you have.

Comment: No don't put number directly in it, define it as a constant value. Check my answer.

Comment: In the java code that I show you, this does not happen, why is it?

Comment: please see the comment in the answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this NUM_PAGE is just a variable which is missing. You can declare this variable like

```
val NUM_PAGE = 3
```

basically this is the number of pages you have. If you had a list variable for the fragments like

```
val list = listOf<Fragment>(SwipeFragement1(), SwipeFragement2(), SwipeFragement3())
```

In that case, NUM_PAGE would be

```
list.size
```

Comment: It seems very good to me but I would like to know why in java I do not have to define the variable, and also I would like to know if the rest of the code is fine

Comment: I am sure you will get exactly same error in Java. Please check the import section of your Java class.

Comment: val list = listOf<Fragment>(SwipeFragement1(), SwipeFragement2(), SwipeFragement3())

@sadat this is not really a good way to keep fragments in a list, they won't get destroyed afterwards.

It's better to create each fragment separated inside getItem(position: Int), exactly on point when you need it. For example if you need 20 different fragments all of them would be referenced, and not destroyed. Consequences of that are leaking memory, etc.

Comment: You had 3 and the answer was just to demonstrate the usage of your unknown variable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code is that you forgot to define NUM_PAGES variable.
You didn't have it yet neither in java code, at least in ScreenSliderPagerAdapter class. Define const variable on top of your class in kotlin, and error will be gone.

```
private const val NUM_PAGES = 3
private class ScreenSliderPagerAdapter
```

Comment: In the java code that I show you, this does not happen, why is it?

Comment: The thing is that NUM_PAGES in your java code was referenced from somewhere else.
Check imports above your java class, probably you will see something like this:
import static .... 
Which means that this variable was imported from some other class inside your project.